# Erro de conexão com o MySQL

Tags: php, mysqli

Estou usando este código:

```
<php?
$sql = mysql_query("SELECT `id`, `detail`, `time` FROM `news` ORDER BY `time` DESC LIMIT 5");
$return = mysql_fetch_assoc($sql); 
while($row = $return) { ?> 
    Data: <?php echo date("d/m/Y", $row['time']); ?> | 
    Noticia: <?php echo $row['detail']; } ?>
```

E quando eu vou rodar esse código, a página fica carregando e não retorna as informações do banco de dados.

Banco de dados:

[image: Banco de Dados]

A conexão com o banco de dados está em outra página, usei o `require();` para pegar a conexão.

Conexão:

`<?php error_reporting(0); $mysql = mysql_connect('localhost', 'root', ''); mysql_select_db('central');`

E a página só carrega e não retorna nada.

Obrigado des de já!

Comment: Apenas um conselho, evite o uso de funções `mysql_*`, use `mysqli_*` (repare quem uma letra "i").  Não quero dizer que isso resolve o problema. O que deve resolver são as respostas abaixo. Isso é apenas um aviso para evitar maiores problemas pois essas funções foram removidas nas versões mais recentes do PHP.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

O problema está nas 2 seguintes linhas:

```
//...
$return = mysql_fetch_assoc($sql); 
while($row = $return) { ?> 
//...
```

A função `mysql_fetch_assoc` deve estar dentro da condição do `while`, ou seja, assim:

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($sql))
```

Isso porque a função `mysql_fetch_assoc` retorna uma matriz associativa que corresponde a linha obtida e move o ponteiro interno dos dados para a linha seguinte.

Por exemplo, se sua query retornar 10 linhas, a função `mysql_fetch_assoc` irá obter os dados da primeira linha, mudar o ponteiro interno para a segunda linha e assim o ciclo é executado 10 vezes até que na 11º o resultado é `false`, uma vez que não há mais linhas.

Quando não há mais linhas, a função retorna `false` interrompendo o ciclo `while`.

Answer (score 1):

Não conheço `PHP`, mas acredito que o método `mysql_fetch_assoc($sql);` deva existir dentro do `while() { }`, assim ele irá carregar uma nova linha a cada volta no while.

Tente algo assim:

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($sql)) { }
```